# How can I tell if my installed Android version, not CPU, is a 64 bit or 32 bit one?

Tags: hardware, system-info

As long as a **64 bit CPU** is supposed to execute **32 bit programs**, it is sometimes hard to know which one do I have installed on my device.

There are programs that require this knowledge, like the [Xposed Framework installer](http://highonandroid.com/android-apps/how-to-install-xposed-installer-on-android-lollipop-5-05-15-1-1/).

What could be considered the **proper method**, whether be it ADB, command-line or software?

I used to do on desktop Linux:

```
 sudo uname -a
```

Maybe there is some equivalent for Android?

Further data:

- Some programs that should inform about this are not clear enoguh for me. This is a example of some AIDA64 report. Even when it shows 32 bit, is this info about the operating system? I would say it is just about the hardware:

  <sub>(Click image to enlarge; my AIDA64 is in Spanish)</sub>

  [image: IMG: AIDA64 report example]

> Question extended to [this other](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/could-a-64-bit-hardware-device-run-a-32-bit-android-version)

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: See this page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/16/how-to-identify-the-image-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-user-space It says to see the property `ro.product.cpu.abi` and the related `ro.product.cpu.abilist32` and `ro.product.cpu.abilist64` in the output of getprop. I don't have a 64-bit device so I can't test few things. There is also a similar question on Quora [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-whether-my-Android-phone-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).

Comment: @New-To-IT , I have multiple Android devices. And, as a computer scientist, I use to work with several different models. Finding a generic method (or, at least, as generic as possible) would be preferred for me. Specifying a device would transform this question in "How can I guess if the installed Android version for my [Brand][Model][Number] is a 64 or 32 bit one?".

Comment: @Firelord : thanks for the link. It seems related to "current device", not "current installed Android version". Would it be the same?

Comment: When it comes to desktop, if you run a 32 bit kernel on a 64 bit machine, the kernel simply says the machine is a 32 bit. Things might have changed (I don't know the current scene) so that's as far as I can tell. May be others can provide a better input.

Comment: @Sopalajo de Arrierez Have you tried Antutu benchmark app? It displays the 32/64 bit information for all devices. ;)

Comment: @Lucky: I have tested AIDA64, and some others tools that report the 32/64 bit information, but none of them sets clear if they are talking about the operating system or the hardware. Added a capture screen to my original question to show.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36291/44325

Comment: @AndrewT. : I don't think that question to be a duplicate, as long as it is asked on 2012, when there were no 64-bit hardware for Android devices. It just ask if the Android (the *existing* then) operating system is a 32 or 64 bits softwarre.

Comment: I'm not really sure either if that's a dupe (that's why I didn't vote to close), but when I researched about this, I never encountered such term as Android OS 64-bit, compared to other OS like Windows (x64). All I found was that it only depends on the CPU architecture, and [Android L is the first 64-bit OS](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/08/first-64-bit-android-phone-has-no-64-bit-software/). Unless that's what you meant, or I'm missing something about 64-bit OS vs CPU on Android, please enlighten me.

Comment: (con't) Other than that, I also never encountered download images for Android with specific bitness (32 or 64), unlike Windows or Linux OS (x86 vs x64).

Comment: Well, @AndrewT. maybe we should start another thread (or change this one) with the title "Is there a 64-bit Android version and a 32-bit one?". Another way to ask it: "Could a 64-bit hardware device run a 32-bit Android version?". Some times the problem is the question, more than the answer.

Comment: I think that's a good idea, since it seems it's easier to have misunderstanding between bitness in Android OS (using SoC) than other OSes (at least I was confused with this topic when researching). But don't change this question since it already has an answer. Either extend this, or post a new question and refer to this question.

Comment: Modified the original question to extend it to the new one, @AndrewT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`uname -m` will display the architecture of the *running kernel*.  This is different than whatever your hardware may be capable of running.

Unfortunately, you have to know which architectures are 32-bit and which are 64-bit. But you can easily find this out.

For example, my m7 displays `arm7l`. A quick search confirms that this is a 32-bit architecture, meaning that my running kernel was compiled as a 32-bit executable.

Comment: But if you check usage of `uname` you get `-m      The machine (hardware) type`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/DTueH.png

Comment: It refers to the machine architecture that the kernel was compiled for. Try installing 32-bit Ubuntu on your 64-bit computer and you will get i686 or some other 32-bit architecture name from `uname -m`.

Comment: As Paul said, `uname -m` can be deceiving. Some relevant details here: [Could a 64-bit hardware device run a 32-bit Android version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217477/218526)