# Could a 64-bit hardware device run a 32-bit Android version?

Tags: hardware

This question comes from [How can I tell if my installed Android version, not CPU, is a 64 bit or 32 bit one?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/126776/96277)

On desktop computers it is possible to install a **32-bit** operating system on a **64-bit** hardware device i.e. you can install Ubuntu Linux 32-bit on an AMD FX(tm)-9370 Eight-Core Processor (64-bit).

Does the same case happens for Android? Is there a **32-bit and a 64-bit version** for the same 64-bit device?

Some example links (like ROM downloads in 32 and 64 bits for the same Android device) would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clearly mentioned but I assume you are talking about ARM architecture. ***“32-bit Android OS”*** means a 32-bit kernel and the collection of ELF binaries and libraries which are compiled to run on 32-bit processor. This middleware stack particularly includes `app_process` binary which runs with name `zygote` and hosts the complete application framework of Android. It forks Java Virtual Machines (for every app) in which Dalvik EXecutable (`.dex`) code runs which is neither 32-bit nor 64-bit. But the JVMs are native processes; either 32 or 64-bit depending on the JNI libraries the app contains.

We can run 32-bit OS on 64-bit device if 64-bit:

1. Processor supports running 32-bit code which is usually the case because backward compatibility is desired, but not always.
2. Kernel supports running 32-bit code because unlike bare-metal hypervisors we - the processes on Android - don't deal directly with hardware.

### PROCESSOR'S BITNESS

Every 64-bit processor's support for 32-bit execution isn't universal. For instance Samsumg Exynos 9 Series 982x SoCs contain [Cortex-A55](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a55) and A75 which (are based on ARMv8.x and they) have support for `aarch64` and `aarch32`. On the other hand Qualcomm's [Centriq 2400](https://www.anandtech.com/show/11737/analyzing-falkors-microarchitecture-a-deep-dive-into-qualcomms-centriq-2400-for-windows-server-and-linux) SoCs and Cavium's [Thunder X2](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/cavium/thunderx2) SoCs also include ARMv8.x processors but without `aarch32` support.

In order to find device architecture, we can read `/proc/cpuinfo` which [exposes](https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/oss-platforms/w/docs/245/cpufreq-dvfs) information from [Main ID register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0488c/CIHFAACD.html) of the processor.

```
~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
...
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
...
CPU part        : 0xd03
...
Hardware        : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8953
```

But there in no direct information like [`lm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D80000001h:_Extended_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) flag to confirm 32/64-bit support. So we need to get technical details of hardware. As per the [requirements](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd#3_3_2_32-bit_arm_native_code_compatibility) from Google, `CPU architecture: 8` indicates that it's a `ARMv8` device. Also see [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/93f22300975017f18c286899e8b98b5d843fe118). And [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/lscpu-arm.c) is the hex to human readable decoding map which `lscpu` command uses.

```
~$ lscpu | grep -E 'Vendor |Model '
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model name:          Cortex-A53
```

Other possible ways to get SoC information:

```
~$ cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model
Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. MSM8953 + PMI8950 QRD SKU3
```

```
~$ cat /sys/devices/soc0/{vendor,family,machine}
Qualcomm
Snapdragon
MSM8953
```

It's evident from technical specifications of Qualcomm Snapdragon 625 ([MSM 8953](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-625-mobile-platform)) and [Cortex-53](https://developer.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a53) that it's based on ARMv8 architecture, which can process both instruction sets: `aarch64` and `aarch32`.

### KERNEL'S BITNESS

When `arm64` support was [added](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8c2c3df31e3b87cb5348e48776c366ebd1dc5a7a) to Linux kernel, 32-bit compatibility mode was also included. If kernel is built with `IKCONFIG_PROC`, confirm by:

```
~# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -E 'CONFIG_ARM64=|CONFIG_COMPAT=|BINFMT'
CONFIG_ARM64=y
CONFIG_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_COMPAT_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT=y
```

So the 64-bit ELF files are executed natively with [binfmt_elf](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/Kconfig.binfmt#L5) while 32-bit ELF files are executed with [compat_binfmt_elf](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/compat_binfmt_elf.c#L3). See details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295968/9165920).).

Usually `uname -m` is used to find the architecture of device supported by kernel. It shows the persoanlity ([execution domain](https://www.halolinux.us/kernel-reference/execution-domains.html)) of the process which defaults to kernel's primary architecture (`PER_LINUX` ). But Linux kernel supports changing [*persoanlity*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html), so this approach can be confusing:

```
~$ uname -m
aarch64
~$ setarch linux32 uname -m
armv8l
```

In latter command `uname` is running under 32-bit [compatible personality](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/arch/arm64/include/asm/compat.h#32). The same would happen if you use some app - like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) - which [runs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/java/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.java#870) with `LINUX32` personality, no matter even if kernel and `uname` binaries are 64-bit. For details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125525/9165920) and [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname#Examples). `lscpu` also confirms CPU operation modes using same phenomenon.

### USERCODE BITNESS

Now coming to the userspace, `init` is the very first process run by kernel. Lets check its bitness. If the 5th byte is 1 it's 32-bit ELF file, if it's 2 the binary is 64-bit:

```
~# hexdump -n5 /proc/1/exe
0000000 457f 464c 0002
```

Or use `file` command:

```
~# file /proc/1/exe
/proc/1/exe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked ...
```

Similarly check bitness of other vital OS binaries/libraries:

```
~$ file /system/lib*/libc.so
/system/lib/libc.so:   ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
/system/lib64/libc.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
```

```
~$ file /system/bin/linker*
/system/bin/linker:        ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
/system/bin/linker64:      ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
```

OS maintains 64-bit as well as 32-bit libraries and dynamic linker because apps may contain both types of binary code (though the major part must be Java/Dalvik bytecode). For instance the `dnsmasq` program which serves as DHCP server on hotspot is a 64 bit binary while Google Play Services uses a 32-bit library:

```
~# readelf -a /system/bin/dnsmasq
  Class:                             ELF64
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
      [Requesting program interpreter: /system/bin/linker64]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
```

```
~# readelf -a /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/ocr/libs/armeabi-v7a/libocr.so
  Class:                             ELF32
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
      [Requesting program interpreter: /system/bin/linker]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
```

Similarly it's not uncommon to have 32-bit binary blobs from OEMs / SoC vendors on 64-bit ROMs. Even some basic components of AOSP aren't 64-bit supported. Take example of [`audioserver`](https://www.mail-archive.com/android-porting@googlegroups.com/msg20926.html).
To see all processes running in 32-bit mode:

```
~# for p in $(ps -p 2 --ppid 2 --deselect -o pid=); do grep -qE '^.{8}[^-]' /proc/$p/maps || echo $p; done | xargs ps f -o pid,cmd -p
  PID CMD
 3359 /system/bin/mediaserver
 3358 /system/bin/cameraserver
 3357 /system/bin/audioserver
 3356 zygote
 5081  \_ webview_zygote
20824  |   \_ com.android.webview:sandboxed_process0
18609  \_ it.colucciweb.vpnclient
 3354 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.audio@2.0-service
 2665 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-service
 2335 /vendor/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon
 2278 /vendor/bin/wifidisplayhalservice
 2277 media.codec hw/android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service
 2244 /system/bin/drmserver
  777 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.drm@1.1-service.widevine
  773 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.cas@1.0-service
```

Out of these only one is a VPN app, rest are OS processes.

### CONCLUSION

So it's clear that even if core OS is 64-bit, there are possibly large number of processes running as 32-bit, though each process and its linked libraries have to be be homogeneous; either 32 or 64-bit. And there's no constraint if the OS doesn't include 64-bit code at all, but you won't find many instances because OEMs ship 64-bit devices with 64-bit binary code. It's more about business than performance; that's what a user pays for. However exceptions do exist where business isn't that much involved: [Raspberry Pi 3 has 64-bit CPU, but 32-bit Raspbian OS](http://linuxgizmos.com/raspberry-pi-3-has-a-64-bit-cpu-but-a-32-bit-raspbian-os). Android phones examples from past include Galaxy E5, LG G Stylo, Moto G5 Plus, Lenovo A6000 Plus and MT6735 devices. But now Android is [moving](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) towards 64-bit and some devices may [drop](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/1ac8a6df9a8ad749e40c5a0f21cd75906a3bcff9) 32-bit support gradually.

> Does the same case happens for Android? Is there a 32-bit and a 64-bit version for the same 64-bit device?

Yes, take example of [Moto G4 Plus](https://www.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus-64-bit-custom-roms/).

---

**RELATED:** [Android apps for “armeabi-v7a” and “x86” architecture: SoC vs. Processor vs. ABI](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. You can run 32bit android on 64 bit chipsets without much hassles. But it shouldn't really matter what version you're on because as of now 90% of all apps that are available are 32bit and won't make use of the 64 bit hardware.

Comment: Some example links would be welcome.

Comment: Your claim that 90% of apps are 32-bit is nonsense, given that most apps are written in Java and thus independent of what ISA and OS you run them on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Infact, Some early devices did exactly that. Its similar to what we have in desktop computing side. Moto E2 is one example of 64-bit processor running  32-bit OS.

Comment: Some example links would be welcome.