# Running "tcpdump" on Android shell gives error: "not executable: 32-bit ELF file"

Tags: shell, android-emulator, android-x86

I'm trying to install `tcpdump` to monitor network traffic. I've tried multiple versions from [link1](https://www.androidtcpdump.com/android-tcpdump/downloads) and [link2](https://www.tcpdump.org/#latest-releases). Whenever I try to execute I get an error:

```
~$ adb connect 192.168.1.10:5555
~$ adb root
~$ adb push tcpdump /data/local
~$ adb shell
~$ su
~# cd /data/local
~# chmod 777 tcpdump
~# ./tcpdump -s 0 -v -w out.pcap
/system/bin/sh: ./tcpdump: not executable: 32-bit ELF file
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
~$ uname -m
i686
```

Comment: using the wrong tcpdump ... Use a 64bit version ( arm64 )

Comment: @Zillinium Where do you recommend I get a 64-bit ? Can't seem to find any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on `x86` architecture but trying to run a `tcpdump` binary built for `ARM` architecture. Link2 provides source code and link1 a 32-bit ARM binary which won't work obviously. You need a 32-bit executable for Intel / AMD processors which you can build from source code, or try [this](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=1395089523397939647) one.

**RELATED:** [ARM vs. x86](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208132/218526).