# How does deodexing work?

Tags: apk, odex

As far as I understand, odexed apps come in two: the "apk" and the "odex" files, both containing different information. And I understand that the odex file has crucial information that loads first and speeds up the booting process.

But I tried to deodex an odexed app with UltimateDeodexer, and it only asked me to upload the .odex file, giving me in return an .apk file. Seemed like it turned the `.odex` into `.apk`.

How does that work?? Is it missing all the information from the original .apk file? Is my resulting .apk file complete, or am I supposed to do something else afterwards?

Comment: The returned APK must be containing the de**O**ptimized **D**alvik **EX**ecutable file like any APK contains `classes.dex` file. Did you check? It'd be better if you explain what you want to achieve with deodexing. For a general understanding see this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225620/218526

Comment: The returned APK files will only contain the dex files, not additional resources and other files you can see when opening the APK file in an ZIP tool.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I do have a classes.dex file. I had a quick look through both apk files' folders, and the only difference seems to be that file. The deodexed apk is slightly bigger, which makes sense, so I guess my resulting apk is complete...? I don't think it's of any help, but I'm trying to change the keyboard apk to use it in a newer phone running another version of android; and I'm a noob, this is the only reason I'm trying to learn android

Comment: *"so I guess my resulting apk is complete...?"* please see Robert's comment.