# able to use the user-installed app even if we remove the app's odex file

Tags: art

I want to get the answers for the following queries:

If I remove the app's odex file from the `data/app/packagename/oat/arm64/base.odex` , then does it mean that the app will run in the same way as it would have run in the Dalvik Virtual Machine (DVM) environment?

Is Android Runtime DVM compatible? The reasons for asking this is I removed the app's odex file as described above and still I am able to run the app?

Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Are you sure the app was not active in background? The Linux base of Android allows to delete the binary of a program while it is executed. Then the program will still have access to the file even so it is no longer present in file-system. Reboot your device to make sure that the app really work without odex.

Comment: Creation of Optimized DEX files is [profile-guided](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure#how_art_works). It doesn't necessarily happen at app installation time. Android may run apps using JIT compiler even without creating `odex` files. And `odex` can be recreated. See may answer to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225620/218526. Further related details can be found in my answer to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221749/218526. Also somewhat related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208132/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526.