# How to know which App architecture is installed on my device? 32bit and 64bit

Tags: 9.0-pie

I've researched a lot about this,

found how to know if the APK is 32bit or 64bit
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348216/how-to-find-if-apk-is-32-bit-or-64-bit

I tried going to the developer area in my phone => process manager and still couldn't see running apps' architecture.

tried installing a couple of task manger apps too, still no luck.

I think Google play automatically detects CPU architecture and installs the correct version

https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#test-64-bit-hardware

and apparently since 2019 August, Google play requires all apps to have a 64-bit version.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

but when I go to Chrome => chrome://version, it shows 32-bit

so I'm looking for a universal way to find out whether the installed app on my phone is 32bit pr 64bit.

I'm using Android 9

Comment: You can look at the output of `adb shell dumpsys package` and check the `primaryCpuAbi` – or use e.g. my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) which creates a device documentation for you, listing the architecture for each app. Unfortunately, this seems not always to be set (for several apps it is just "null" – in which case Adebar cannot show it either).

Comment: Java apps are neither 32-bit nor 64-bit: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208132/218526 Bitness matters only if app includes prebuilt native libraries inside `.apk`. In this case extract the `.apk` (in any unzip utility) and check the binaries or `.so` files using e.g. `file` command or `hexdump` etc.