# How to run 64 bit apps on a 32 bit Android smartphone without root access?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-j5

I know it's difficult or rather almost impossible to change a 32 bit to 64 bit with or without root but is it possible to run 64 bit apps on a 32 bit Android smartphone without root access ?
I am using Samsung Galaxy J5 Prime.

Comment: Theoretically it is possible but in the end it is like manually installing a different custom ROM. The main problem is that you need a 64bit kernel and therefore for all components in your phone you need 64bit drivers. Drivers for phone components are mostly not open source which makes it difficult to get them. And as your device has a 32bit ROM installed it's current kernel is 32bit, hence it can't be reused. Even if you would find a 64bit ROM for your device most likely the apps/games you want to run would still not work because your phone has only 2GB RAM and 64bit phone usually have more.

Comment: Android apps aren't 32-bit or 64-bit. But they may contain arch-specific native libraries/executables. Details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208132/218526). In this case the app usually contains the native binaries for multiple architectures, and as they [state](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit): *"Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures"*. So you need to be specific which app you are talking about. Generally you cannot run 64-bit code on 32-bit hardware.