# Does Google Nexus6 support 64bit android apps?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, processor

I have a 64bit android application with "minSdkVersion=20" (means it can be installed on Android 4.4 above).

My question is:

can this application be installed on Google Nexus6 with android 6 ( Marshmallow)??

Does Google Nexus 6 support 64bit apps at all??

Thanks.

Comment: According to GSMArena the Nexus 6 has an Krait 450 CPU which means it is ARMv7 =32bit only.

Comment: Possibly related (but not yet answered): [How to run 64-bit apps on a 32-bit Android smartphone without root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233961/44325). Android apps themselves are independent of bitness; [only if they contain native libraries](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208087/44325). Does the app only contain 64-bit native libraries, not the corresponding 32-bit ones?

Comment: @AndrewT. It only contains 64-bit native libraries. thank you too.