# Boot Linux from stick in Termux

Tags: usb, linux, termux

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220677) explains in detail why it's basically impossible to boot Linux from a USB stick.

But I am still wondering: is it possible to load and "boot" a stick-bound Linux distro from a USB stick using the Termux terminal app? It can already access files from sticks and run other distros like Arch, so I'd imagine it to be quite possible.

I'm open about the specifics. I'll take whatever distro works.

The idea is to setup a stick-bound persistent Linux instance for specific tasks. I want to run this Linux both on PC and android through the same USB-Stick, although I'd settle for an android-only solution at this point.

Comment: A Linux that works on Andorid devices (ARM) and PCs (x86) does not exist. The kernel and all binaries have to be compiled for one specific architecture.

Comment: You cannot ["boot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting) Linux from a USB stick due to the limitations explained in the answer you already linked. But you can always run ***any Linux environment*** using [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) from ***any storage media*** that works on your device, using ***any terminal app***. But make sure your distro is built for your device architecture, as Robert said. PCs are usually x86_64 and mostly Android devices are ARM. But x86 PCs and phones also exist. Arch is explained in this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208132/218526