# getprop: abi vs abilist

Tags: cpu, build.prop

I was reading [this blog post](https://handstandsam.com/2016/01/28/determining-supported-processor-types-abis-for-an-android-device/) on determining the supported ABIs for a phone.  It said that, prior to Lollipop, the command is

```
getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```

whereas, after Lollipop, it's

```
getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist
```

My phone is running Android 11 and I note that both properties are supported by `getprop`.  Specifically, `abi` is `arm64-v8a` and `abilist` is `arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi`.

Is the support on post-Lollipop devices for `getprop ro.product.cpu.abi` just for backwards compatibility and, hence, `abi` is just returning the first item in `abilist` or does the `abi` value hold more significance?

Comment: Most likely, yes it is for compatibility.

Comment: `abilist` shows a list of [supported ABIs](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208132/218526) on your device.

Comment: @IrfanLatif, that I know.  I'm curious as to how `abi` is different from Lollipop onward.