# Is it normal for an Android OS upgrade to change bitness on an upgrade?

Tags: updates

I support an Android app, that uses native files. (multiple APKs)
Some app setup is done on first startup, (which is different for 32bit + 64bit).

Recently I dealt with a bug report, caused by a users OS being upgraded from Android 7.1 to android 8.1. Surprisingly to me, the OS changed from 32bit to 64bit. I don't have direct contact with the user, so I don't know if this was the user manually upgrading the OS on a rooted device, or a standard OS upgrade.

Is this a normal thing that can happen for non rooted devices?

Comment: I don't think that should happen but isn't technically impossible. Some details in my answer to [Could a 64-bit hardware device run a 32-bit Android version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217477/218526)

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about what was happening.

I was using a C#/Xamarin call to determine the OS bitness : "`Environment.OSVersion.VersionString"`
Which I mistakenly believed would tell me the os bitness rather than process bitness.
(I was already using `IntPtr.Size` to determine process bitness)