# How am I supposed to know if my smartphone is ARM or 86x?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I have a Sony Xperia M and installed CyanogenMod a couple of times. When ever I want to download GAPPS, I wonder, if my Smartphone is ARM or x86, and when ever I google it and don't find an answer, I have a deja vú  and I just go with ARM since it is most common and my phone is probably ARM.

But shouldn't there be a way to find out?

Comment: Related: [How can I tell if my installed Android version, not CPU, is a 64 bit or 32 bit one?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/126776)

Comment: Did you read [How to identify the android device is 32-bit or 64-bit?](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/16/how-to-identify-the-image-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-user-space) BTW, at least OpenGApps employs a check for compatibility before installation, so even if you end up downloading incorrect GApps version you would still be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi` gives you the hardware answer (e.g. "arm64-v8a" for my Wileyfox Swift).
- `adb shell uname -m` tells you what the kernel is running (e.g. "aarch64" for the same device)

If you do not have ADB setup (and don't plan to), you can run the same commands in a terminal app. Just skip the preceding `adb shell` then:

```
$ getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
arm64-v8a
$ uname -m
aarch64
$
```

Comment: saved us thank you